# Velodyne VLP-16 sensor driver - Ros2 on Windows 10

Tags: ros2, rviz, windows10, velodyne-driver

I just installed ROS2 foxy desktop on my Windows 10 PC, I am going to install velodyne driver and use Rviz to visualise the data from my Velodyne VLP-16 sensor. but i can not find any tutorial about that.
Please give me some instructions.
Best regards,